# Need help calling a method using an object and another class in a driver

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I'm having trouble creating the object student1 that calls on and prints out the menu method I have created. Help would be appreciated. This is a driver class that calls onto the class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StudentDriver
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Student student1 = new Student();
        student1 = menu();
        System.out.println(student1);



    }
    public Student menu(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName, String eNumber, String major, 
                               String concentration, int creditHours, int qualityHours)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = 0;
        Student student1 = new Student(student1);


        while((choice < 9))
        {
            System.out.print("\nPress number to enter input: ");

            System.out.print("\n-------------------------------");

            System.out.println("\n1. First Name ");
            System.out.println("2. Middle Name ");
            System.out.println("3. Last Name ");
            System.out.println("4. E-Number ");
            System.out.println("5. Major ");
            System.out.println("6. Concentration ");
            System.out.println("7. Credit Hours ");
            System.out.println("8. Quality Hours ");
            System.out.println("9. Exit ");

            System.out.print("What would you like to enter? ");
            int option = kb.nextInt();

            if(option == 1)
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter the first name: ");
                firstName = kb.nextLine();
                student1.setFirstName(firstName);

            }

            else if(option == 2)
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter the middle name: ");
                middleName = kb.nextLine();

                student1.setMiddleName(middleName);
            }

            else if(option == 3)
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter the last name: ");
                lastName = kb.nextLine();
                student1.setLastName(lastName);
            }

            else if(option == 4)
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter the E-Number: ");
                eNumber = kb.nextLine();
                student1.setENumber(eNumber);
            }

            else if(option == 5)
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter the major: ");
                major = kb.nextLine();
                student1.setMajor(major);
            }

            else if(option == 6)
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter the concentration: ");
                concentration = kb.nextLine();
                student1.setConcentration(concentration);
            }

            else if(option == 7)
            {
                System.out.print("\nPlease enter the credit hours: ");
                creditHours = kb.nextInt();
                student1.setCreditHours(creditHours);
            }

            else if(option == 8)
            {
                System.out.print("\nPlease enter the quality hours: ");
                qualityHours = kb.nextInt();
                student1.setQualityHours(qualityHours);
            }

            else 
            {
                break;
            }


        }
            return student1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ignore my answer if you saw it, I mistook something and the information was incorrect. Catchwa has the correct info.

Answer (score 2):

1) This constructor doesn't make any sense:

```
Student student1 = new Student(student1);
```

This is what I was getting at in requesting a self-contained example as you're the only one that can see your internal logic behind `Student`. Change it to a no-args constructor if you're going to be setting all the fields anyway.

```
Student student1 = new Student();
```

(Of course, you need to change this in the `Student` class definition too)

2) Make menu a static method that returns a `Student` object

```
public static Student menu()
```

3) Then, make the first lines of the `menu()` method set the variables you're going to need:

```
String firstName, middleName, lastName, eNumber, major, concentration;
int creditHours, qualityHours;
```

The code below compiles and shows the menu, which I think is what you're stuck on:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StudentDriver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Student myStudent = menu();
        System.out.println(myStudent);
    }

    public static Student menu()
    {
        String firstName, middleName, lastName, eNumber, major, concentration;
        int creditHours, qualityHours;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = 0;
        Student student1 = new Student();

        while((choice < 9))
        {
            System.out.print("\nPress number to enter input: ");

            System.out.print("\n-------------------------------");

            System.out.println("\n1. First Name ");
            System.out.println("2. Middle Name ");
            System.out.println("3. Last Name ");
            System.out.println("4. E-Number ");
            System.out.println("5. Major ");
            System.out.println("6. Concentration ");
            System.out.println("7. Credit Hours ");
            System.out.println("8. Quality Hours ");
            System.out.println("9. Exit ");

            System.out.print("What would you like to enter? ");
            int option = kb.nextInt();

            if(option == 1)
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter the first name: ");
                firstName = kb.nextLine();
                student1.setFirstName(firstName);

            }

            else if(option == 2)
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter the middle name: ");
                middleName = kb.nextLine();

                student1.setMiddleName(middleName);
            }

            else if(option == 3)
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter the last name: ");
                lastName = kb.nextLine();
                student1.setLastName(lastName);
            }

            else if(option == 4)
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter the E-Number: ");
                eNumber = kb.nextLine();
                student1.setENumber(eNumber);
            }

            else if(option == 5)
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter the major: ");
                major = kb.nextLine();
                student1.setMajor(major);
            }

            else if(option == 6)
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter the concentration: ");
                concentration = kb.nextLine();
                student1.setConcentration(concentration);
            }

            else if(option == 7)
            {
                System.out.print("\nPlease enter the credit hours: ");
                creditHours = kb.nextInt();
                student1.setCreditHours(creditHours);
            }

            else if(option == 8)
            {
                System.out.print("\nPlease enter the quality hours: ");
                qualityHours = kb.nextInt();
                student1.setQualityHours(qualityHours);
            }

            else 
            {
                break;
            }
        }
            return student1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an actual Student class but I know it is right. I just don't know how to to print out the menu in the driver.

Comment: @Byrdman1219 when posting code it should be self-contained. Otherwise, it's difficult for people to compile your samples themselves.

Comment: @Byrdman1219 As Catchwa said; also, ensure you post the exact error message(s), and / or describe aberrant behaviour, otherwise we're stuck guessing what your specific problem is.

Comment: The error with the code above is a cannot find symbol for the student1.menu(); in line 9. The error states that it can't find symbol

Comment: `student1.menu();` Well, does your `Student` class have a `menu()` method? We can't tell because we can't see that class. This also looks fishy `Student student1 = new Student(student1);` You want to create an object student1, but you are passing it as a parameter before you have made it?